# Changing how SQL query resultswill display using a drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays, drop-down-menu

I am using the method below to change the display-style of queried SQL results using a drop down menu. I'm trying to create the **option for normal or gallery view**, etc.  I haven't been able to find any information on this (which only means I'm not searching the right things, or taking the right approach). I'm also trying to use INCLUDE external files to centralize the design.

This approach has not been working for me. Mostly because the included files are full of code with quotes/double-quotes (too many to escape).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBlocks = new Array(
    '<?php include "../include/normal_view.php" ?>',
    '<?php include "../include/gallery_view.php" ?>',
    '<?php include "../include/mini_view.php" ?>');
    function changeView(elemid) {
    var ind = document.getElementById(elemid).selectedIndex;
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=textBlocks[ind];}
</script>

<form>
<select id="whatever" onChange="changeView('whatever');">
<option value="0">Normal</option>
<option value="1">Gallery</option>
<option value="2">Minimum</option>
</select><br>
</form>

<div id="display"><?php include "../include/normal_view.php" ?></div>
```

The pages being INCLUDED are similar to the following;

```
<div id="normal_view">
  <?php 
      $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM db_whatever");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="normal_view">
            <ul>
                <li class="price"><?php echo $row['PRICE']; ?></li>
                <li class="address"><?php echo $row['ADDRESS']; ?></li>
                <li class="bed"><?php echo $row['BEDS']; ?></li>
                <li class="bath"><?php echo $row['BATH']; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
<?php } //end of loop ?> 
</div>
```

Is this the right approach?
If so, is there a way I can command the script to ignore all commas/double-commas from the INCLUDED files?
Can you recommend a good tutorial or examples to follow out there?

Comment: What do the *_view.php files do?  Is it merely styling or also functionality?  Because you could instead load a style sheet based on a url parameter

Comment: @Rachael I corrected a typo to answer your question >  "The pages being INCLUDED are similar to the following;" So the included *_view.php files each run queries, which are displayed differently for each file. This is how I figured to accomplish the functionality. Not sure if this the standard approach, or what?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you're using the right approach.

HTML should be included as HTML, not as a text string in javascript. 
You can have them on `display: none` until you need them. No need to escape any quotes.

Comment: That's what I figured too, but since I originally there was TEXT as string,  I thought HTML might work too.  I'm still searching for how this function is performed.